# Upgrading iMac G3 memory

Tags: imac, hardware, powerpc

I got an iMac g3 450 mhz (summer 2000 i think) and i want to upgrade its memory. I know i need PC 100/133 168 pin . I already got one 512mb from amazon with those specs although it didn't work. For some reason all the memories that say they are compatible with mac are x3/4 the price of the rest of same technology. Any suggestions as to where I should look for memory or any spec I should be looking for in order for it to be compatible ?

Comment: From what manufacturer was the RAM chip that didn't work?

Comment: Did you try [Crucial](http://www.crucial.com/)?

Comment: http://www.amazon.co.uk/512MB-PC133-168-PIN-MEMORY-DESKTOPS/dp/B001CZ4BS4/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1329533462&sr=8-1

Comment: Crucial are overpriced they cost £40 or more .

Comment: On the other hand Crucial provides OEM  chips for the Mac.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do not worry about getting one that is specifically "for iMacs." Any 168-pin PC 100/133 chip should fit just fine.

I have been working with several iMacs over the last few weeks. From my experience with them, a slot-loader seems to max out at around 1GB (two 512mb chips.)

If your RAM is not working, you likely got a bad chip. See if you can exchange it for another one.